# How to display a video template if a "video" field exists in firestore?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-cloud-firestore

Hello I'm trying to display a video using ***template literals*** everything is working fine but now I wish to hide the template if the ***video*** field in firestore is empty or doesn't exists

[image]

If the field ***video*** has the embbed value in firestore the video correctly displays

[image]

But if the field ***video*** doesn't have any value then the ***iframe*** tag still shows up and I'd like
to hide it

Here is my code

```js
const video  = document.getElementById('video');
let path3 = `Ludolab/offer/list/${idRef}/index/${idCon}/content`;
let collRef3 = db.collection(path3);
collRef3.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
  video.innerHTML = '';
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    video.innerHTML +=`  
    <iframe class="has-ratio" width="150" height="150" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/${doc.data().video}" 
            frameborder="0" allowfullscreen> 
    </iframe>
                         
        `
  });
});
```

Any help is gladly appreciate it, thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the default value of video field or is it just missing from document at first place? If the field exists then try setting that to null and try out the code in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a simple `if` statement that adds another `iframe` only when video field is present:

```js
collRef3.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
  video.innerHTML = '';
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    if (doc.data().video) {
      // video field present, add iframe
      video.innerHTML += `  
    <iframe class="has-ratio" width="150" height="150" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/${doc.data().video}" 
            frameborder="0" allowfullscreen> 
    </iframe>`
    }
  });
});
```